# Joomla 2.5 loading stuck on database configuration for localhost

Tags: database, joomla2.5

The installation of Joomla on localhost does not proceed after step 4. Database Configuration.
It keeps on loading and loading and never stops. 
And in my Database I get min 25 to max 60 tables(on various attempts) but not after that.

Im using

```
WAMPSERVER version 2.4 -> Apache 2.4.4, PHP 5.4.16, MySQL 5.6.12

Joomla -> Joomla_2.5.13-Stable-Full_Package

OS -> Windows 7 32 BIT

Browsers used -> Mozilla FireFox & Google Chrome.
```

The information I've used is

```
Database Type= Mysqli (tried both mysqli and mysql - still the same) 
Host Name = localhost
MySQL User Name = root
MySQL Password = blank 
MySQL Database Name = joomla_lab
MySQL Table Prefix = jos_ (this is set as default)
```

I searched a lot but cant find the solution. Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but can you create a user who uses a password on mysql admin panel.

Comment: yeah I can.. Let me try that.

Comment: Did so and got this error

`Could not connect to the database. Connector returned number: Unable to connect to the Database: Could not connect to MySQL.`

Comment: Sorry i don't know why.

Comment: @Auster Just to let you know and anyone with a similar problem that I found the solution. What I did was that I un-installed Wamp 2.4 and installed a lower version wamp 2.2 for 32 bit Windows 7 and everything worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Run as administrator....? Might help if your on a windows system. So run Apache as Administrator.